# Chrome extension - corporate account - ExtensionsSettings policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a chrome extension that is running well on private accounts but we tackled with the following error on some accounts:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: This page cannot be scripted due to an ExtensionsSettings policy.`

The extension has content script and edits some pages.

How can we fix this?

Comment: The only solution is to change ExtensionsSettings policy and include the extension's id in runtime_allowed_hosts. See the policy documentation for more info.

Comment: Who is in charge of changing the ExtensionSettings policy?

Comment: Usually the same person who manages all domain policies.